# How can I whitelist my private nexus on maven 3.8?

Tags: maven, repository, nexus

It seems like maven 3.8 has  introduced some kinf of MITM attack protection, doing that it drops all the connections to the private repositories (such as nexus sonatype and so on). Here it is what happens when I try to download dependencies that are hosted into my private repository

[image]

And it stays there, waiting forever...

The private repositories are defined into the settings.xml file and everything worked perfectly (with mvn 3.6.3) until maven 3.8.

How can I put such private repositories in the "maven trusted" ones?

Here it is the settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>first-profile</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>my-nexus</id>
                    <url>http://nexus.mycompany.com:8081/repository/dev/</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>my-nexus</id>
            <username>username</username>
            <password>password</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>first-profile</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>

</settings>
```

Comment: Please show the settings.xml file you are using? If you have repos in your pom files that's wrong...

Comment: @khmarbaise I have added the settings.xml example (removed sensitive info) in the question text.

Comment: That's exactly what I expected. You are not using your repository manager... Best would be like this: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html#using-a-single-repository. so you use your repo manager only which will solve the problem...But you must be check if your repo manager proxies central repo if not you should change the configuration and fix that...

Comment: Thank you, I had already seen it but I wasn't sure if it was the correct solution. What if I want to maintain the "profiles" structure?

Comment: You can of course use a profile for that, but it usually makes no sense...

Comment: Try copying the central repo information from the [super POM](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html) to your profile.However, as mentioned by someone else, I also doubt that you need this as part of your profile.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the shipped **mirror** tag from `/opt/maven/conf/settings.xml` by placing a new variant into the user's `settings.xml`, only adding local repo ids to be not considered by the `mirrorOf` rule, worked for me.

Maven 3.8.x

```
<settings>
    <mirrors>
        <!-- a copy of /opt/maven/conf/settings.xml, so can override with exception rules -->
        <mirror>
          <id>maven-default-http-blocker</id>
          <mirrorOf>!my-repo1,!my-repo2,external:http:*</mirrorOf>
          <name>Pseudo repository to mirror external repositories initially using HTTP.</name>
          <url>http://0.0.0.0/</url>
          <blocked>true</blocked>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
</settings>
```